rustup doesn't install toolchain?
Complete newb to rust I'm afraid, just trying to install it for the aws cli, anyway..
I have rustup and cargo installed but for some reason rustup refuses to install a toolchain. It says it is both up-to-date and not installed:
$ rustup --verbose toolchain install --force stable
verbose: read metadata version: '12'
verbose: installing toolchain 'stable-i686-apple-darwin'
verbose: toolchain directory: '/Users/rich/.rustup/toolchains/stable-i686-apple-darwin'
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-i686-apple-darwin'
verbose: creating temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/c3zs1m83q45lr1sv_file
verbose: downloading file from: 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256'
verbose: downloading with reqwest
verbose: deleted temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/c3zs1m83q45lr1sv_file
verbose: no update hash at: '/Users/rich/.rustup/update-hashes/stable-i686-apple-darwin'
verbose: creating temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/9yxkef68j5im2ilq_file.toml
verbose: downloading file from: 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml'
verbose: downloading with reqwest
verbose: checksum passed
verbose: creating temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/zlh5ifnl73hbtvyy_file
verbose: downloading file from: 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.asc'
verbose: downloading with reqwest
verbose: deleted temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/zlh5ifnl73hbtvyy_file
verbose: Good signature from on https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml from:
verbose: from builtin Rust release key
verbose:   RSA/85AB96E6-FA1BE5FE - Rust Language (Tag and Release Signing Key) <rust-key@rust-lang.org>
verbose:   Fingerprint: 108F 6620 5EAE B0AA A8DD 5E1C 85AB 96E6 FA1B E5FE
verbose: deleted temp file: /Users/rich/.rustup/tmp/9yxkef68j5im2ilq_file.toml
info: latest update on 2024-03-28, rust version 1.77.1 (7cf61ebde 2024-03-27)
verbose: toolchain is already up to date

  stable-i686-apple-darwin unchanged - (toolchain not installed)

info: checking for self-updates
info: downloading self-update

$ rustup show
Default host: i686-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/rich/.rustup

(error: toolchain 'stable-i686-apple-darwin' is not installed, not a directory: '/Users/rich/.rustup/toolchains/stable-i686-apple-darwin')

EDIT - try uninstall:
$ rustup uninstall stable
info: no toolchain installed for 'stable-i686-apple-darwin'

$ rustup --verbose toolchain install stable
verbose: read metadata version: '12'
verbose: installing toolchain 'stable-i686-apple-darwin'
verbose: toolchain directory: '/Users/rich/.rustup/toolchains/stable-i686-apple-darwin'
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-i686-apple-darwin'

...

info: latest update on 2024-03-28, rust version 1.77.1 (7cf61ebde 2024-03-27)
verbose: toolchain is already up to date

  stable-i686-apple-darwin unchanged - (toolchain not installed)

info: checking for self-updates
info: downloading self-update

It looks like 1.73.0 is the last supported version in my MacOS 10.11, but this doesn't work either:
rustup --verbose toolchain install 1.73.0

no joy unfortunately :(

Nope, the toolchains dir is empty

The toolchains dir didn't exist either until I manually created it with drwxr-xr-x, didn't make any difference

Try rm "$HOME/.rustup" -r

neither --allow-downgrade nor removing .rustup makes any difference

Are you running on an intel or apple silicon mac? If intel try stable-x86_64-apple-darwin rather than stable. If apple silicon try stable-aarch64-apple-darwin

Even if your running apple silicon, it might be worth trying stable-x86_64-apple-darwin, though you'll have to run it through rosetta.

I'm not sure x86_64 will work because I had to install the i686 version of rust-init for the same reason - I got an executable error.

This was a MacOS 10.11 compatibility issue. I installed the i686 version of rust-init so it wanted to use the i686 toolchains, which don't appear to exist for the latest version. So I fixed it with:
(1.73.0 appears to be the latest compatible 10.11 version):
rustup --verbose toolchain install 1.73.0-x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup default 1.73.0-x86_64-apple-darwin

Thanks to user1937198 for the hint!
